# Query to select all rows since last success

Tags: mysql, group-by

Given my following table structure:

[image]

I'm trying to build a query that will return the number of **failed login attempts** per IP *since* the last successful login of that same IP within the past hour.

For instance, you'll notice there are several failed attempts `(0)` from a single IP within the past hour, but since the last successful login (#145) there has only been 1 (#146), which is what I want returned.

This query should also be dynamic and return rows of grouped IPs.

So far this is what I have, but I think `@ipa` is returning `NULL`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) tries, @ipa := login_ip
FROM login_log
WHERE login_id > (
    SELECT MAX(login_id)
    FROM login_log
    WHERE login_success = 1
    AND login_ip = @ipa
)
AND login_success = 0
AND login_date > NOW() - 3600
GROUP BY login_ip
ORDER BY tries DESC;
```

Thanks

Comment: It does not seem you are setting `@ipa` before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias the table and try it this way, as your `@ipa` variable is doing nothing for you:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) tries, l.login_ip
FROM login_log l
WHERE login_id > (
    SELECT MAX(login_id)
    FROM login_log l2
    WHERE l2.login_success = 1
    AND l2.login_ip = l.login_ip
)
AND login_success = 0
AND login_date > NOW() - 3600
GROUP BY login_ip
ORDER BY tries DESC;
```

Additionally, you can do this with a `join`:

```
select
    count(1) tries,
    log1.login_ip
from
    login_log log1
    inner join (
        select
            login_ip,
            max(login_date) as max_date
        from
            login_log
        where
            login_success = 1
        group by
            login_ip
    ) log2 on
        log1.login_ip = log2.login_ip
where
    log1.login_success = 0
    and log1.login_date > NOW() - 3600
    and log1.login_date > log2.max_date
group by
    login_ip
order by tries desc
```

You can try both ways and see which one is faster for you.

Comment: Missing a comma at the end of line 8 on the second one, but otherwise it works! And it's faster since I don't have to do a sub-query.  Thanks!

Comment: @stevether - Ah, sorry about the missing comma. Fixed :) And to clarify, you are doing a subquery, just not a correlated subquery. The difference is that the former runs only once, while the latter runs *for each row*, which can take a little time.

Comment: How might I get this to work if there was never a successful login for an IP? It's just not returning a row for it, but it should.

Comment: Change `inner` to `left` and then change `and log1.login_date > log2.max_date` to `and log1.login_date > coalesce(log2.max_date, '1900-01-01')`